# SFTP directory sync app for Android

Tags: android, sftp

Having:

- a few local directories on an Android phone
- an SFTP server with pubkey auth and available via the internet

Purpose (searching an app for it, even if it is a one-time pay app):

- sync the few local directories about immediately to the SFTP server (two way, so if someone deleted a file from the SFTP, it will be deleted from the phone too!)

Is there an app for this?

So far what I found all had some issues with these simple points (didn't supported ssh key auth, only pw or it didn't listed my id_rsa file.. or it only syned daily once..)

Comment: Haven't tried it myself, but from the description [AndFTP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lysesoft.andftp) might fit. It explicitly lists synchronization, and explicitly states "SSH RSA/DSA keys support". Not sure whether [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite) meanwhile supports SSH keys (description doesn't say, and it's long ago I last checked as I no longer have access to PlayStore). There's also [Syncopoli](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.amoradi.syncopoli/) using rsync via SSH with keys.

Comment: Looks like http://www.tacit.dk/foldersync is what you're looking for.